# Error: md-datepicker should not be placed inside md-input-container

Tags: angular-material

When trying to wrap `<md-datepicker>` with `<md-input-container>`

I get an error like the one above, however one of examples from the [project page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input)
comes with that structure

```
<md-input-container>
   <label>Enter date</label>
   <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of anxious, unproductive research I updated Angular Material from `1.0.7` to `1.1.0`  and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I am using `1.1.0` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try to disable browser cache?